# GAS embedded in Google Site requests "insecure resource" whereas it worked before

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sites

I am using Google Apps Script's Visualization API to generate charts/tables and have about a dozen such scripts successfully embedded in Google Sites.  Yesterday, I created a new script and tried to embed it into a Site by [Edit Page | Insert | Google: Apps Script] as usual.  I received the following error seen in the Console:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://sites.google.com/a/globalfoundries.com/aleister_projects/'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://sites.google.com/a/globalfoundries.com/sites/system/errors/WebspaceNotFound?path=%2Fmacros%2Fs%2FAKfycbwuIGzoNErAzb2mqL5HRrVc6xeQTaavvycUXLhi1rSVSeF1ZUSM%2Fexec'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

After some unsuccessful trouble-shooting with my new script, I attempted to embed a second copy of an existing script that I know has successfully generated a table into an existing Site directly below the existing copy of this script (see attached image).  The result is that the original copy of the script that was embedded a few months ago renders fine, but the re-embedded copy inserted directly below it generates this error.

[image: Evidence: Exhibit A]

Is anyone having this issue?  Has anyone seen this issue?  Can anyone provide some insight?  I'm not sure if there is some security change at my organization or if there is some Google-side update about which I am unaware.  Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and this is what I did to solve it:

I noticed that the format /exec link generated has changed.

Old format (supported in classic google site)
https://script.google.com/a/macros/your-domain.com/s/xxxxxxxxxxx_S61g09Dk/exec (macro was before the domain)

New Format (not supported in classic google site)
https://script.google.com/a/your-domain.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxx_S61g09Dk/exec (macro is now after the domain)

Modifying the url after generation is the only solution I found. Hope this will help you.

Comment: after moving "macros" within the URL my charts/tables render without issue.  I hadn't noticed that (unannounced?) change!  You've been a tremendous help; thank you kindly!